# How can I sort a list of dictionary by two keys, in which the second key should be sorted in descending order

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

How can I sort a list of dictionary by two keys, in which the second key should be sorted in descending order.
I have a list which contains a number of dictionaries, the format is:

```
result = [{'so':ABC,'so_value':123.0,'inv':'ADV-025'},
{'so':PQR,'so_value':19.0,'inv':'908025'}]
```

I want to sort the list by keys 'so' (ascending) and 'inv'(descending). How can I do this with `itemgetter` in python?

- **EDIT:**

  I have tried the following but it will sort only by ascending order. result = sorted(result, key=itemgetter('so', 'inv'))

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Christian I have tried the following but it will sort only by ascending order.
result = sorted(result, key=itemgetter('so', 'inv'))

Comment: @GopakumarNG Add that as well to the question, otherwise this might be closed for no effort.

Comment: And post the expected output as well.

Comment: Note that in the above SO post I've said this is a duplicate of, the accepted answer provides a method to sort by an **arbitrary** number of keys, or which some can be "negated" (reversed) by prepending the key with a - (minus) sign. This I believe covers your case completely

Comment: Don't fear classes.  They'd make this a cinch.

Answer (score 1):

I'd write my own compare function, so the cmp argument in [sorted](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)

Example (sorted on so ascending first, and on inv descending second):

```
from operator import itemgetter

input = [{'so':'PQR','so_value':19.0,'inv':'908025'},{'so':'ABC','so_value':123.0,'inv':'ADV-025'}]

def compare(x, y):
    (xso, xinv) = x
    (yso, yinv) = y
    socmp = cmp(xso,yso) #compare so
    if socmp == 0: #if so are equal, compare inv
        return -cmp(xinv, yinv) #minus for descending order
    else:
        return socmp

print sorted(input, cmp=compare, key=itemgetter('so','inv'))
```

Note that this is basically a simplified and less general version of the one in the post referenced by three_pineapples. If you understand this, I'd advise you to look at that link for a more general solution.